# ¿Como extraer filas de un DataFrame con los valores máximos para una variable en R?

Tags: r

[image: DataFrame con 5 columnas (variables)]

Tengo un DataFrame (DF) y quiero extraer las filas que tienen los valores máximos de una de sus variables. 
Para el ejemplo, extraer las cinco filas que tienen los valores más altos de Abundancia.

De antemano muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando un `data.frame` genérico de R como `mtcars` queremos obtener las 5 filas dónde el valor de la variable `disp` se mayor, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
mtcars[order(-mtcars$disp),][1:5,]

                     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8  460 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8  440 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8  400 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

- Ordenamos el vector correspondiente a la columna `disp` de mayor a menor mediante`order(-mtcars$disp)`, lo cual genera un vector nuevo con los índices de cada fila según el orden dado
- Luego simplemente es extraer los valores y recortar las primeras 5 filas con `mtcars[...,][1:5,]`

Posiblemente más óptimo sea recortar directamente el vector del orden a los 5 casos deseados, si bien el resultado será el mismo: `mtcars[order(-mtcars$disp)[1:5], ]`

Por otro lado, si ya usas o piensas usar `dplyr` para manipular los datos la sintaxis es también muy concisa y clara, aunque en este caso los resultados tendrán el orden original del `data.frame`:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
    top_n(5, disp)
```